# Meaning of "to week"

Tags: word-meaning

I'm trying to pinpoint the meaning of *to week* in *[Mary Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Hamilton)* folksong, e.g. covered by Joan Baez ([lyrics](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/2735468/Joan+Baez/Mary+Hamilton)):

*You need not weep for me she cried

You need not week for me*

It looks similar to *to weep*, *to cry*. It could be an intentional error to track plagiarism as well. Could someone cast some light on this verse?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a misheard (mistrancribed) lyric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I think you are either hearing it incorrectly or are working from an incorrect transcription of the lyrics. The word "week" does not occur in the song you mentioned.

[Here are the lyrics](https://genius.com/Joan-baez-mary-hamilton-lyrics)

Comment: It makes sense, I was looking at the lyrics proposed by Google, which contain the wrong transcription. What about *to dee* a couple of lines below? (I can create a new question if you prefer).

Comment: 'Dee' is Scottish dialect pronunciation & spelling of 'die'.

Answer (score 1):

Typo or misheard

> Oh you need not weep for me she cried
>   You need not **weep** for me

[Mary Hamilton](https://genius.com/Joan-baez-mary-hamilton-lyrics)